# How to run javascript using browser

Tags: javascript, file, browser

Is it possible to run javascript (.js file) using only browser?
Namely this one:
https://github.com/croxis/PlutoTime
No browser I have tried is able to show the "PlutoTime" from the original NASA page, so I hoped I could run it offline localy, but no success...
Is the browser good enough, or do I need some compilator or so..?
I have tried Firefox 30.0, it shows javascript only as text. MSIE say just "error happened".

Comment: You could just paste the code into a site like jsfiddle.net

Comment: or in a code snippet here ^^

Comment: Well, I have Firefox on Windows, I have the javascript file. What next?